# C++ std::find with a custom comparator

Tags: c++, stl

This is basically what I want to do:

```
bool special_compare(const string& s1, const string& s2)
{
    // match with wild card
}

std::vector<string> strings;

strings.push_back("Hello");
strings.push_back("World");

// I want this to find "Hello"
find(strings.begin(), strings.end(), "hell*", special_compare);

// And I want this to find "World"
find(strings.begin(), strings.end(), "**rld", special_compare);
```

But `std::find` doesn't work like that unfortunately. So using only the STL, how can I do something like this?

Comment: A side comment - the string arguments in compare should be `const string&` not just `string&`. Interesting question btw.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Based on your comments, you're probably looking for this:

```
struct special_compare : public std::unary_function<std::string, bool>
{
  explicit special_compare(const std::string &baseline) : baseline(baseline) {}
  bool operator() (const std::string &arg)
  { return somehow_compare(arg, baseline); }
  std::string baseline;
}

std::find_if(strings.begin(), strings.end(), special_compare("hell*"));
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was trying to do.

Answer (score 12):

The function you need to use is this : [`std::find_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find), because `std::find` doesn't take compare function.

But then `std::find_if` doesn't take *value*. You're trying to pass *value* and *compare* both, which is confusing me. Anyway, look at the [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find). See the difference of the usage:

```
auto it1 = std::find(strings.begin(), strings.end(), "hell*");
auto it2 = std::find_if(strings.begin(), strings.end(), special_compare);
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Basically I want to compare each string in `strings` with the `"hell*"` and match it with the wild card. So it would find "Hello". Hope that makes more sense.

Comment: @Josh: So think you need `find_if`, and you need implement *compare* function accordingly.

Comment: I might be wrong but doesn't the *compare* function only take 1 argument? How would I compare it to the "hell*" string I'm trying to find?

Comment: @Josh: You can use `"hell*"` inside the function itself, no need to pass to it. In fact, the compare function takes only one argument. Or you could use function-object, if you want to make it generic.

Answer (score 12):

You'll need `std::find_if()`, which is awkward to use, unless you're on a C++11 compiler. Because then, you don't need to hardcode the value to search for in some comparator function or implement a functor object, but can do it in a lambda expression:

```
vector<string> strings;

strings.push_back("Hello");
strings.push_back("World");

find_if(strings.begin(), strings.end(), [](const string& s) {
    return matches_wildcard(s, "hell*");
});
```

Then you write a matches_wildcard() somewhere.

Comment: Lambdas are definitely the way to go. No reason to create a whole comparator class for something simple like this, especially with pretty much everyone having a C++11(+) compiler.

Answer (score 7):

With C++11 lambdas:

```
auto found = find_if(strings.begin(), strings.end(), [] (const std::string& s) { 
    return /* you can use "hell*" here! */;
});
```

If you can't use C++11 lambdas, you can just make a function object yourself. Make a type and overload operator ().

Answer (score 7):

Since nobody has mentioned [`std::bind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind) yet, I'll propose this one

```
#include <functional>

bool special_compare(const std::string& s, const std::string& pattern)
{
    // match with wild card
}

std::vector<std::string> strings;
auto i = find_if(strings.begin(), strings.end(), std::bind(special_compare, std::placeholders::_1, "hell*"));
```

Comment: bind applies on C++11, but can be avoided on C++11 using lambda as @nikos-c stated.

Answer (score 3):

I wanted to have an example with custom class having custom find logic but didn't find any answer like that. So I wrote this answer which uses custom comparator function (C++11) to find an object.

```cpp
class Student {

private:  
  long long m_id;
  // private fields

public:
  long long getId() { return m_id; };
  
};
```

Now suppose, I want to find the `student` object whose `m_id` matches with a given id. I can write `std::find_if` like this:

```cpp
// studentList is a vector array

long long x_id = 3; // local variable
auto itr = std::find_if(studentList.begin(), studentList.end(),
                    [x_id](Student& std_val) 
                    { return std_val.getId() == x_id; }
                    );

if(itr == studentList.end())
  printf("nothing found");
```