# does stl help to to search a big array in faster way in c++?

Tags: c++, templates, search

I have a big matrix could be as big as 10000x10000 or even bigger. I am going to search all the index of elements within some values and that process will be repeated for many times. The c++ code looks

```
double data[5000][5000];
int search_number = 4000;
double search_main_value[4000];
vector<int> found_index[4000];

// fill search main value array here 
// search_main_value[0] = ...;
// ...
// search_main_value[3999] = ...;

for (int n=0; n<4000; n++)  // for each search main value
{
  for (int row=0; row<5000; row++)
  {
    for (int col=0; col<5000; col++)
    {
      double lb = search_main_value[n]-0.5;
      double ub = search_main_value[n]+0.5;
      if ( (data[row][col]>=lb) && (data[row][col]<ub) )
      {
        found_index[n].push_back(col*5000+row);
      } 
    }
  } 
}
```

But this search is so slow if the size of array is too big and the search_value_array is big. I am trying to use std algorithm to boost the search but I read the help, it seems that the stl container only works for searching a number at a time but not a range.

===================================================

I follow the example given online like

```
bool compare(const double& num, const double&d) {return ( (num>=d-0.5) && (num<d+0.5))}

double *start = data;
double *end = data+5000*5000;

for (int n=0; n<4000; n++)
{
  auto found = find_if(start, end, std::bind(compare, std::placeholders::_1, search_main_value[n]);
}
```

But this doesn't compile, it said std doesn't have bind. Also, it seems that it returns the found values not the index. And how can I save the found to a std::vector? I try

```
std::vector<double> found_vec;
found_vec.assign(found);
```

But it doesn't compile.

===========================================================

I also try to sort the data first and then search the data with binary_search

```
struct MyComparator
{
  bool operator()(const pair<double, int> &d1, const pair<double, int> &d2) const {return d1.first<d2.first;}
  bool operator(double x)(const pair<double, int> &d) const {return (d.first>=x+0.5) && (d.first<0.5);}
};

std::vector< std::pair<double, int> > sortData;
// fill sortData here with value, index pair

std::sort(sortData.begin(), sortData.end(), MyComparator()); // it works
...
std::find_if(sortData.begin(), sortData.end(), MyComparator(search_main_value[n]));
```

but the last code doesn't compile

Comment: You can use a customer comparator, such as in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14322299/c-stdfind-with-a-custom-comparator

Comment: @jogojapan i think you mean custom?

Comment: `((data[row][col]-0.5)>=search_main_value[n]) && ((data[row][col]+0.5)<search_main_value[n])` I don't see how this condition could ever be true. It boils down to `X-0.5 >= Y && X+0.5 < Y`. But if `X-0.5 >= Y` is true, then `X >= Y+0.5` and `X+0.5 >= Y+1`, and then `X+0.5 < Y` can't be true.

Comment: @Borgleader Yes, sorry for the typo.

Comment: sorry for the misleading code, I copy the wrong code. I've edited my post

Comment: @jogojapan: The accepted answer in the link you gave uses `std::unary_function` which is **deprecated** in C++11.

Comment: @Nawaz You can still use `std::find` with custom comparators. And not everyone uses C++11, for all kinds of reasons.

Comment: @Nawaz Also, this is Stackoverflow. Go and write a new answer for that question with the updated recommendation for C++11.

Comment: @jogojapan: Hehe. I just wanted to make a note that `std::unary_function` is **deprecated**. so the C++11 code doesn't use it anymore.

Comment: @Nawaz Sure, that's true. I must also say that in any case, my link is probably not the best possible one. My point really is that information on how to use `std::find` is custom ways is readily available, even from SO, and certainly from cppreference etc.

Comment: Thanks all. I try to follow the example given in the link but it looks quite abstract to me. It doesn't compile and I post the code in the original post also

Answer (score 4):

Since this process is going to be repeated multiple times, I would suggest you to sort the elements and store it in a vector along with index as a pair. And you could be able to find the essential index or indices easily given this vector.

```
      vector<pair<int, int> > sortedElementsWithIndex;
```

Pair contains element and index in the original array. you could sort this vector according to the element value.

Comment: Yes. Sort the array and use binary search later on.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. I have created the vector array as suggested above. And then I apply sort to sort the array. But how do I search the sorted vector ?

Comment: Do a binary search until your predicate passes. From that element, access immediate previous elements sequentially until the predicate becomes false and all those elements into the result array. Same way, access next elements until your predicate becomes false and add it to your result array. It wouldn't be that complex and give fast results, if the elements in the result array is very less comparing with the original.

Comment: I try the following code the code shown in the edited post, but it doesn't compile.

Comment: The binary search algorithm is called `std::lower_bound()` (there is also an algorithm call `std::binary_search()` but it probably doesn't quite do what you need it to do: it merely returns a `bool` indicating if the sought value is in the range).