# std::find_if compare function compiler error

Tags: c++, stl

I'm writing a simple program to familiarize with c++ and its core libraries, since i just started looking at it.

Following [C++ std::find with a custom comparator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14322299/c-stdfind-with-a-custom-comparator) accepted answer ( https://stackoverflow.com/a/14322617/611901 ) I wrote

```
struct special_compare : public std::unary_function<composerRating, bool>
    {
        explicit special_compare(size_t id) : id_(id) {}
        bool operator() (const composerRating &cr_arg) const {
            return cr_arg.composerID == id_;
        }
        size_t id_;
    };

    vector<composerRating>::iterator crIter = find_if(ratings.begin, ratings.end(), special_compare(ID));
```

But the compiler complains that `find_if` doesn't take this kind of arguments. I saw on other answers that they use bind, but it is used when they need to call the member of a class, while I'm passing the class (struct) itself. In addition, I would prefer to avoid to use boost since I'm just writing a few lines program and it seams that std::bind is not in the scope of the function, and I didn't find a bind library.

What should I do to solve the problem?

Comment: `ratings.begin, ratings.end()` The lack of syntactic symmetry in those arguments is worrying.

Comment: shouldn't it be `rating.begin()` ?

Comment: I feel so dumb!
I'm not used yet to the fact that functions without parenthesis doesn't raise compiler error.
Thanks to both!

Comment: BTW all that `unary_function` stuff is deprecated in C++11.