# combine boost unordered_map, bind, and std::find_if

Tags: c++, boost

I have a big container of boost::unordered_map like below:

```
typedef boost::unordered_map< vertex, entity > vertex_container;
```

The vertex class has a coordinate member variable representing its location.
I have several coordinate point_(s). I would like search if any vertex inside my container exist so that vertex.coordinate = point.

something like:

```
vertex_container::iterator it = std::find_if(v_container.begin(), v_container.end(), boost::bind(&Vertex::coordinate(), _1) == point);
```

but it fails.

I tried:

```
vertex_container::iterator it = std::find_if(v_container | boost::adaptors::map_keys(boost::bind(&vertex::coordinate(), _1)) == point);

error: cannot call member function ‘mesh::coordinate mesh::Vertex::coordinate() const’ without object.
```

I somehow try to combine boost unordered_map, bind, and std::find_if.

Please **NOTE** I am only able to use C++09 standard and boost 1.53.0 version.

Comment: `it fails` is not a diagnostic we can go on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you need to do is to first bind the key out of the unordered_map and then bind again the member function.

```
vertex_container::iterator it = std::find_if( v_container.begin(), v_container.end(), (boost::bind(&vertex::coordinate, (boost::bind( &vertex_container::value_type::first, _1))) == point) );
```

and also you cannot use pipe within std::find_if.

Answer (score 0):

In your code you have :

```
boost::bind(&Vertex::coordinate, _1) == point
```

this is a comparison between `boost::bind(...)` and point, and, since it is a comparison, it is a boolean value. Or more probably, your compiler doesn't know how to compare the two.

`std::find_if` takes a function returning boolean as argument.

This means, since you're on <`c++11` you'll have to declare a function somewhere like:

```
bool isVertexEqualToPoint(Vertex*, point){
  return vertex.coordinate==point;
}
```

and then you can `boost::bind` that function to compare against your point. 
I do think however that is is more elegant here to  make a compare object. Have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14322299/c-stdfind-with-a-custom-comparator). It should be straightforward. Just replace the `somehow_compare` with your own condition.