# How to search std::string for substring with wildcard c+

Tags: c++, string, search

So I have a vector of strings all the same word size.

I want to be able to search them for adjacent words.

Meaning king would have adjacent words: bing, sing, kong, kind, and so on.

I'm thinking to speed it up instead of comparing each character in every word against king, I could do a find() function that searches for the strings that contain kin*, ki*g, k*ng, and *ing.  Then make a 2nd map of all the words that have those combinations.

But how would I make the find function search strings using a wild card character?

Comment: You could use the [Regular Expressions Library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex).

Comment: As you have a list of words, may be you can try boost regex search.http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/ref/regex_search.html

Comment: Also look into suffix trees. Edit: I personally like the [Trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie)

Comment: *I'm thinking to speed it up*... You say it is about speed, but then I fail to see how the idea of "*searching for the strings that contain kin., ki.g, k.ng, and .ing*" will provide any speed up?? The same applies to the suggestion of using "Regular Expressions".. How will they speed up things? The fastest for your case should be a basic, simple, straightforward comparison character by character, stopping as soon as two characters dont match.

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oanapl/archive/2009/04/04/performance-comparison-regex-versus-string-operations.aspx I was told that regex was slower than string operations

Comment: I suggest looking into usage of find_if
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/find_if/

or

https://stackoverflow.com/a/14322617/3990012