# Find string in vector of strings case insensitive c++

Tags: c++, string, vector, find, case

I have

```
std::vector<std::string> vec;
std::string myString;
```

and I need to find out if `myString` is in `vec` using **case insensitive** comaprisons.

I know I can use

```
find(vec.begin(), vec.end(), myString) != vec.end())
```

to answer the question "is myString in vec?" but that will do case sensitive comparisons. I need case insensitive comparisons.

The position is not important, I just want to know if myString is in vec or not.

Comment: Should this do the trick? [enter link description here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14322299/c-stdfind-with-a-custom-comparator)

Comment: [Related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11635/case-insensitive-string-comparison-in-c).

Answer (score 4):

You need to use std::tolower and std::find_if:

```
    std::vector<std::string> vec = {"ALF", "B"};
    std::string toSearch = "Alf";
    auto itr = std::find_if(vec.begin(), vec.end(),
                [&](auto &s) {
                    if ( s.size() != toSearch.size() )
                        return false;
                    for (size_t i = 0; i < s.size(); ++i)
                        if (::tolower(s[i]) == ::tolower(toSearch[i]))
                            return true;
                    return false;
                }
    );
    if ( itr != vec.end()) {
        std::cout << *itr << std::endl;
    }
```

Comment: I like this answer but ... the code is actually wrong. To Fix it:

    `if( std::tolower(s[i]) != std::tolower(newServerName[i]) )
          return false;
     return true;`

So change the comparision and swap the return values. Otherwise all strings with a matching first character are considered equal...

Answer (score 4):

Or, for a *much* smaller and easier-to-read solution, Boost!

```
// #include <algorithm>
// #include <boost/algorithm/string/predicate.hpp>

const auto it = std::find_if(
   std::begin(vec),
   std::end(vec),
   [&myString](const auto& str) { return boost::iequals(myString, str); }
);

const bool found = (it != std::end(vec));
```

Comment: On what planet is Boost "much smaller"?

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `std::find_if` and provide a custom comparator. To achieve case insensitive comparison I would advise you to convert both strings you want to compare to a common case: lower or upper. That would lead to a code like the following:

```
auto ret = std::find_if(vec.begin(), vec.end(),
    [&myString](const std::string& s) {
        if (s.size() != myString.size())
            return false;
        return std::equal(s.cbegin(), s.cend(), myString.cbegin(), myString.cend(), [](auto c1, auto c2) { return std::toupper(c1) == std::toupper(c2); });
    });
```

This will return an iterator which will be `vec.end()` if no occurrence of `myString` was found. You can do whatever you please with that iterator (including comparing it to `vec.end()` to know if you found your string).

Bonus: running minimal example on [Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f65a02ec04625969)

Comment: @jotik I wanted to make a full statement, he can do whatever he likes with the returned iterator. Be it simply comparing it to `vec.end()` or counting the number of occurrences (or w/e)

Comment: There is no `std::toupper(std::string&)`, it accepts a char

Comment: Note that this solution doesn't work for Unicode strings.

Answer (score 2):

You may use `std::find_if`, an inline lambda and `std::tolower` to make the comparison:

```
//Computing the lower version of mystring
std::string my_string_lower;
my_string_lower.reserve(mystring.size());
std::transform(mystring.begin(), mystring.end(), std::back_inserter(my_string_lower), ::tolower);

// Checking if it is exist in the vector:
auto is_exist = std::find_if(vec.begin(), vec.end(), [&my_string_lower](std::string item){
    //Transform the each vector item to lower temporally 
    std::transform(item.begin(), item.end(), item.begin(), ::tolower);
    return mystring==item;
}) != vec.end();
```

if you are going to search many times in the same vetor of string, it would be better if you compute it once:

```
//Computing the lower version of the whole vector
std::vector<std::string> vec_lower;
vec_lower.reserve(vec.size());
std::transform(vec.begin(), vec.end(), std::back_inserter(vec_lower),[](std:string item){
    std::transform(item.begin(), item.end(), item.begin(), ::tolower);
    return item;
});

//Computing the lower version of mystring
std::string my_string_lower;
my_string_lower.reserve(mystring.size());
std::transform(mystring.begin(), mystring.end(), std::back_inserter(my_string_lower), ::tolower);

// Checking if it is exist in the lower version of the vector:
auto is_exist = std::find_if(vec_lower.begin(), vec_lower.end(), [&my_string_lower](const std::string& item){
    return mystring==item;
}) != vec_lower.end();
```

Comment: `std::tolower` takes a char not a std::string

Answer (score 2):

```
template <class T>
long VecFindIgnoreCase( const std::vector< T >& vec, const std::string& sFind ) {
    return VecFindIgnoreCase( vec, sFind.c_str() );
}

template <class T>
long VecFindIgnoreCase( const std::vector< T >& vec, const char* sFind )
{
    for ( std::vector< T >::const_iterator iter = vec.begin(); iter != vec.end(); ++iter )
        if ( _stricmp( (*iter).c_str(), sFind ) == 0 )
            return (long)std::distance( vec.begin(), iter );
    return -1;
}

template <class T>
long VecFindIgnoreCase( const std::vector< T >& vec, const std::wstring& sFind ) {
    return VecFindIgnoreCase( vec, sFind.c_str() );
}

template <class T>
long VecFindIgnoreCase( const std::vector< T >& vec, const wchar_t* sFind )
{
    for ( std::vector< T >::const_iterator iter = vec.begin(); iter != vec.end(); ++iter )
        if ( _wcsicmp( (*iter).c_str(), sFind ) == 0 )
            return (long)std::distance( vec.begin(), iter );
    return -1;
}
```

Use:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>

void TestCode()
{
    std::vector< std::string > strvecA;
    std::vector< std::wstring > strvecW;

    strvecA.push_back("abc");
    strvecA.push_back("def");             
    strvecA.push_back("ghi");
    strvecW.push_back(L"abc");
    strvecW.push_back(L"def");
    strvecW.push_back(L"ghi");

    long ind;

    ind = VecFindIgnoreCase( strvecA, "ABC" ); // ind = 0 found
    ind = VecFindIgnoreCase( strvecA, "ghI" ); // ind = 2 found
    ind = VecFindIgnoreCase( strvecA, "Xyz" ); // ind = -1 not found

    ind = VecFindIgnoreCase( strvecW, L"aBc" ); // ind = 0 found
    ind = VecFindIgnoreCase( strvecW, L"DEF" ); // ind = 1 found
    ind = VecFindIgnoreCase( strvecW, L"xyZ" ); // ind = -1 not found

    std::string sFind( "mno" );
    if ( (ind = VecFindIgnoreCase( strvecA, sFind )) >= 0 ) {
        // found at strvecA[ind]
    } else {
        // not found
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the performance of `std::find` is better than `std::count`, I have to implement a function template to search in `std::vector` :

```
template <class Iterator>
Iterator Find(Iterator first, Iterator last, const char *value)
{
    while (first != last)
    {
        if (StrCmpIA((*first).c_str(), value) == 0)
        {
            return first;
        }

        first++;
    }

    return last;
}
```

Now you can use of the template function like this :

```
vector<string> vecStr = {"ali", "reza", "hamid", "saeed"};

if (Find(vecStr.begin(), vecStr.end(), "saeeD") != vecStr.end())
{
    cout << "found" << endl;
}
else
{
    cout << "not found" << endl;
}
```