# C++ std::find for strings ignoreres lower/upper case?

Tags: c++, oop, stl

I need for a class a function which checks if a string is contained in another. Did I understand right that the STL function std::find for strings ignore lower and upper case (that is what I need)?

Comment: why do you think `std::find` would be case-insensitive?

Comment: No you understand wrong.

Comment: Use `std::find_if` instead and supply a function to do the case insensitive comparison.

Comment: your question is kind of vague, what exactly are you tryinjg to do?

Comment: To use @john solution this thread may help https://stackoverflow.com/q/36494584/6865932

Comment: In recommend you to provide full description of your problem, to avoid misunderstanding. Issue can be more complex then you can imagine, for example if your string is UTF-8 encoded.

Comment: Also, why did you not try this before asking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> find searches for an element equal to value

std::string::find iterates over the range and returns the position to the first element satisfying the condition or last is no match was found.

if you pass a substring contained in a larger string to the std::find function, the algorithm should return the position where the substring starts.

std::string::find is not case insensitive, it just iterates the container and checks if the substring is present

Comment: `std::find` returns an iterator and finds characters in strings, not substrings. Maybe you refer to `std::string::find`(but that also returns no pointer)

Comment: also not an iterator to the last element is returned, but an iterator one past the last element if the element could not be found

Comment: yes, it returns std::string::npos, and yes it is std::string::find @idclev463035818, thank you for the correction. aren't iterators just a generalization of pointers though ?

Comment: vehicle is a generalization for car, but yet planes are no cars ;)

Answer (score 1):

[`std::string::find`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find/) does not perform a case-insensitive search; it searches for an exact match. You would have to convert both the string to search and the search term to either lower or upper case first, and then use `std::string::find`.

However, there is another way you could do it with modern C++ (C++11 onward): use `std::regex_search` with the `std::regex_constants::icase` flag:

```
bool findCaseInsensitiveRegex(const std::string &completeString, const std::string &toSearch)
{
    std::regex pattern(toSearch, std::regex_constants::icase);
    return std::regex_search(completeString, pattern);
}
```

where `toSearch` is a regex made from the string to search for, and `completeString` is the complete string to search in.

Examples of both methods [here](https://godbolt.org/z/1shz58).